# MySQL query to find items ordered at least once that have not been ordered lately

Tags: mysql

I simplified the query and the table, but to give you some context: I have an "orders" table that contains all the items ordered by customers.
I want to check which items have been ordered at least once in history, but then, for whatever reason, nobody ordered them anymore (in this case, 180 days but it's just an example).

```
SELECT DISTINCT (idItem)
FROM orders
WHERE myDate < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 180 DAY) 
  AND 
    (idItem NOT IN 
      (SELECT 
         DISTINCT(idItem) 
         FROM orders 
         WHERE myDate > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 180 DAY)
      )
    ) 
ORDER BY myDate
```

This was my reasoning: I pick all the items ordered MORE THAN 6 months ago, and from the result I keep only the ones that DO NOT APPEAR in the previous 6 months.

I have 2 problems: one, it gives me back basically all of them, and second, regardless of "distinct", I still get plenty of duplicates :(

I do not usually deal with SQL, I know enough for simple queries but this one is probably as complex as I can make them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT idItem
FROM orders
GROUP BY idItem
HAVING 0 = SUM(myDate > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 180 DAY))
```

?

Comment: Wow, I would have never came up with that :) From the first tests, it seems ok. Give me 15 minutes to do more testing and I will accept it!

Answer (score 0):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.idItem
FROM orders o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM orders
  WHERE idItem = o.idItem AND myDate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 180 DAY)
)
```

Comment: It gives me different results than @Akina and, in particular, it does not show one item that I tested and it's 100% surely correct. Sorry I do not have the knowledge to debug what's different :( But thank you for showing me another command that I should start to learn too :)

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` works as expected: it rejects any `idItem`s ordered after `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 180 DAY)` so there is no case to return wrong results. Check your code and maybe use `curdate()` instead of `now()`.